# Can Jupyter run a separate R notebook from within a Python notebook?

Tags: r, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have a Jupyter notebook (python3) which is a batch job -- it runs three separate python3 notebooks using `%run`. I want to invoke a fourth Jupyter R-kernel notebook from my batch.

**Is there a way to execute an external R notebook from a Python notebook in Jupyter / iPython?**

Current setup:

`run_all.ipynb`: (python3 kernel)

```
%run '1_py3.ipynb'
%run '2_py3.ipynb'
%run '3_py3.ipynb'
%run '4_R.ipynb'
```

The three python3 notebooks run correctly. The R notebook runs correctly when opened separately in Jupyter -- however it fails when called using `%run` from `run_all.ipynb`. It is interpreted as python, and the cell gives a python error on the first line:

> ```
> cacheDir <- "caches"
> ```
>
> TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

I am interested in any solution for running a separate R notebook from a python notebook -- Jupyter magic, shell, python library, et cetera. I would also be interested in a workaround -- e.g. a method (like a shell script) that would run all four notebooks (both python3 and R) even if this can't be done from inside a python3 notebook.

(NOTE: I already understand how to embed `%%R` in a cell. This is not what I am trying to do. I want to call a complete separate R notebook.)

Comment: Do you depend on sharing variables across the notebooks, such that if you ran `2_py3.ipynb` on it's own it does not work, and it only works when ran in the same notebook as `1_py3.ipynb`? Or can they all be ran separately?

Comment: They can all run completely separately -- no runtime variable / state sharing -- they only independently access common files in the file space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can use the `%run` magic command that way as it executes the file in the current kernel.

Nbconvert has an execution API that allows you to execute notebooks. So you could create a shell script that executes all your notebooks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 1_py3.ipynb
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 2_py3.ipynb
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 3_py3.ipynb
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 4_R.ipynb
```

Since your notebooks require no shared state this should be fine. Alternatively, if you really wanna do it in a notebook, you use the execute Python API to call nbconvert from your notebook.

```
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

with open("1_py3.ipynb") as f1, open("2_py3.ipynb") as f2, open("3_py3.ipynb") as f3, open("4_R.ipynb") as f4:
    nb1 = nbformat.read(f1, as_version=4)
    nb2 = nbformat.read(f2, as_version=4)
    nb3 = nbformat.read(f3, as_version=4)
    nb4 = nbformat.read(f4, as_version=4)

ep_python = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')
#Use jupyter kernelspec list to find out what the kernel is called on your system
ep_R = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='ir')

# path specifies which folder to execute the notebooks in, so set it to the one that you need so your file path references are correct
ep_python.preprocess(nb1, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
ep_python.preprocess(nb2, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
ep_python.preprocess(nb3, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
ep_R.preprocess(nb4, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})

with open("1_py3.ipynb", "wt") as f1, open("2_py3.ipynb", "wt") as f2, open("3_py3.ipynb", "wt") as f3, open("4_R.ipynb", "wt") as f4:
    nbformat.write(nb1, f1)
    nbformat.write(nb2, f2)
    nbformat.write(nb3, f3)
    nbformat.write(nb4, f4)
```

Note that this is pretty much just the example copied from the nbconvert execute API docs:  [link](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am working through these examples to see if they work. If it helps for updating the example, the R kernel for Jupyter I am using is `ir` `$ jupyter kernelspec list`: ir : /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir

Comment: This example writes to the original filename, and will update the original notebook cells with output, BUT if something goes wrong it will corrupt or blank out the entire notebook file. It might be safer as a default example to write to a new file?

Comment: Thank you -- this gave me everything I needed to solve my problem. In particular, it worked very well to simply call a line from your example shell script using in-notebook shell magic.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47053020/7207622) to implement two solutions to running an R notebook from a python3 notebook.

#### 1. call nbconvert from `!` shell command

Adding a simple `!` shell command to the python3 notebook:

`!jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute r.ipynb`

So the notebook looks like this:

1. `%run '1_py3.ipynb'`
2. `%run '2_py3.ipynb'`
3. `%run '3_py3.ipynb'`
4. `!jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 4_R.ipynb`

This seems simple and easy to use.

#### 2. invoke nbformat in a cell

Add this to a cell in the batch notebook:

```
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

rnotebook = "r.ipynb"
rnotebook_out = "r_out.ipynb"
rnotebook_path = '/home/jovyan/work/'

with open(rnotebook) as f1:
    nb1 = nbformat.read(f1, as_version=4)

ep_R = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='ir')
ep_R.preprocess(nb1, {'metadata': {'path': rnotebook_path}})

with open(rnotebook_out, "wt") as f1:
    nbformat.write(nb1, f1)
```

This is based on the answer from Louise Davies (which is based on the nbcovert docs example), but it only processes one file -- the non-R files can be processed in separate cells with `%run`.

If the batch notebook is in the same folder as the notebook it is executing then the path variable can be set with the `%pwd` shell magic, which returns the path of the batch notebook.

When we use nbformat.write we choose between replacing the original notebook (which is convenient and intuitive, but could corrupt or destroy the file) and creating a new file for output. A third option if the cell output isn't needed (e.g. in a workflow that manipulates files and writes logs) is to just ignore writing the cell output entirely.

#### drawbacks

One drawback to both methods is that they do not pipe cell results back into the master notebook display -- as opposed to the way that `%run` displays the output of a notebook in its result cell. The `!jupyter nbconvert` method appears to show stdout from nbconvert, while the `import nbconvert` method showed me nothing.