# How to run a Jupyter notebook from a notebook with a different kernel?

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a Jupyter notebook (R) from within a notebook (Python). Using the command:

```
%run "DESeq2 Analysis.ipynb"
```

Calls the Noteook and runs it, but gives a Python error. The notebook that is being called (DESeq2 Analysis.ipynb) should be run with the R kernel. DESeq2 Analysis.ipynb runs fine with the R kernel when I run it independently. What appears to be happening is the calling notebook running with a Python 3 kernel is calling DESeq2 Analysis.ipynb and trying to run the code with the Python 3 kernel instead of R kernel.

Is there a way to specify the kernel when using the %run command?

Comment: This answer indicates a way to achieve this through `nbconvert`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47053020/1388292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Louise Davies [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47053020/1388292) to [Can Jupyter run a separate R notebook from within a Python notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047376/can-jupyter-run-a-separate-r-notebook-from-within-a-python-notebook)

> I don't think you can use the `%run` magic command that way as it executes the file in the current kernel.
>
> Nbconvert has an execution API that allows you to execute notebooks. So you could create a shell script that executes all your notebooks like so:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 1_py3.ipynb
> jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 2_py3.ipynb
> jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 3_py3.ipynb
> jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute 4_R.ipynb
> ```
>
> Since your notebooks require no shared state this should be fine. Alternatively, if you really wanna do it in a notebook, you use the execute Python API to call nbconvert from your notebook.
>
> ```
> import nbformat
> from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
>
> with open("1_py3.ipynb") as f1, open("2_py3.ipynb") as f2, open("3_py3.ipynb") as f3, open("4_R.ipynb") as f4:
>     nb1 = nbformat.read(f1, as_version=4)
>     nb2 = nbformat.read(f2, as_version=4)
>     nb3 = nbformat.read(f3, as_version=4)
>     nb4 = nbformat.read(f4, as_version=4)
>
> ep_python = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')
> #Use jupyter kernelspec list to find out what the kernel is called on your system
> ep_R = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='ir')
>
> # path specifies which folder to execute the notebooks in, so set it to the one that you need so your file path references are correct
> ep_python.preprocess(nb1, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
> ep_python.preprocess(nb2, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
> ep_python.preprocess(nb3, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
> ep_R.preprocess(nb4, {'metadata': {'path': 'notebooks/'}})
>
> with open("1_py3.ipynb", "wt") as f1, open("2_py3.ipynb", "wt") as f2, open("3_py3.ipynb", "wt") as f3, open("4_R.ipynb", "wt") as f4:
>     nbformat.write(nb1, f1)
>     nbformat.write(nb2, f2)
>     nbformat.write(nb3, f3)
>     nbformat.write(nb4, f4)
> ```
>
> Note that this is pretty much just the example copied from the nbconvert execute API docs:  [link](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html)

Comment: In the `preprocess` step, does the executed notebook access current globals defined in the calling notebook?